# Aligning annotations and variables in parameters IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For instance, I have this currently with my settings:

```
public foo(@Annotation1 String str,
           @Annotation2 Integer int,
           @SomeLongerAnnotation List<String> l,
           boolean b){}
```

What I'm looking to do is this:

```
public foo(@Annotation1          String       str1,
           @Annotation2          Integer      int1,
           @SomeLongerAnnotation List<String> l1,
                                 boolean      b){}
```

so that the annotations are aligned on their own, and the variables and their types are aligned on their own. Is it possible for Intellij to auto-format it in that way?

Comment: Not possible. You can vote for [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164136).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' think its possible.   I tried.  As an alternative you could format it yourself then in Settings|Code Style panel check the box that says "Enable formatter markers in comments"

Then you can have the formatter ignore a section of code as follows (ugly and probably not what you want).  If it were me I'd just get used to the defaults and move on with whatever I was working on...

```
    // @formatter:off
    public Test(@NotNull String         str,
                @NotNull Integer        ints,
                @NotNull List<String>   l,
                boolean b) {
    }
    // @formatter:on
```